# Specify Gradle Report Directory

Tags: gradle

I have several folders trying to seperate my tests up into unit, integration, 3rd party, db. This way I can have my tests seperated into chunks purposes, to make TDD easier/faster. Here is the task that I am trying to use.

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
    maxParallelForks 8
    maxHeapSize = "4048m"
}
```

I know there is [testReportDir](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test%3atestReportDir), but it's deprecated. I want to be able to use the new method.

I have tried the following closures:

```
reports {
    html = file("$buildDir/reports/intTests")
}

reports {
    setDestination = file("$buildDir/reports/intTests")
}

reports {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/intTests")
}

destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/intTests")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want

```
integrationTest.reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/intTests")
```

You may want to consult the [api docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestTaskReports.html) for `TestTaskReports` which shows that the html report is a `DirectoryReport` extending `ConfigurableReport` and that that provides the [destination](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/reporting/ConfigurableReport.html#setDestination%28java.lang.Object%29) accessor referred to in the one liner above.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted & most upvoted answer may be out-of-date now.

I used

```
test {
    reports.html.outputLocation = file("<ouput-dir>")
}
```

which worked and didn't give a deprecation warning. This is called out in [Gradle 7 -> Gradle 8 migration guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#report_getoutputlocation_return_type_changed_from_provider_to_property)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement your own task of type [TestReport](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport.html) similar to [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#subProjectsTestReport). Note the feature is incubating though.